# Spring Data REST pagination

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

When migrating from Spring Boot **1.4** to **2.0**, everything went smoothly until I tested the pagination feature. In short, I have a web MVC `@RestController` with a method that returns a `Page<MyDTO>`. Originally, the response would serialize in JSON quite straightforward:

```
{
  "content": {},
  "last": true,
  "totalElements": 18,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "direction": "ASC",
      "property": "id",
      "ignoreCase": false,
      "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
      "ascending": true
    }
  ],
  "numberOfElements": 18,
  "first": true,
  "size": 50,
  "number": 0
}
```

But after migrating, I get something like:

```
{
  "content": {},
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "sorted": false,
      "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "unpaged": false,
    "paged": true
  },
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 1,
  "last": true,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "first": true,
  "numberOfElements": 1
}
```

I wouldn't mind much, except that deserialisation doesn't work, even after trying to tweak the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and set some abstract type resolvers.

The official Spring doc is not very extensive on how to proceed, it seems to handle perfectly if one uses `Repositories` and `@RestResource`. But what is the correct and preferred way to handle paging when exposing your API through an MVC controller?

**EDIT** Adding stacktrace and more context

Running my `RestTemplates` clients over existing code will result in the following stacktrace. Although this is not really important, I can get around it by implementing a custom `Pageable` sub-class (as well as `Sort`) and configuring a `MessageConverter` to use them. The underlying question is *how should a Page instance be serialized/deserialized in JSON using the latest Spring Boot stack?*

```
ERROR b.o.c.a.handler.CrisExceptionHandler - Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4802] (through reference chain: be.ondd.cris.service.integration.util.RestResponsePage["pageable"]) 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4802] (through reference chain: be.ondd.cris.service.integration.util.RestResponsePage["pageable"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:629)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.integration.InformationProviderCRISService.searchInformationProvider(InformationProviderCRISService.java:85)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.integration.InformationProviderCRISService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$adc25943.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at be.ondd.cris.api.aspect.LoggingHandler.logAround(LoggingHandler.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.integration.InformationProviderCRISService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51eda584.searchInformationProvider(<generated>)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.ProductMapperService.mapPageProductToPageProductJson(ProductMapperService.java:126)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.ProductMapperService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4257f2af.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at be.ondd.cris.api.aspect.LoggingHandler.logAround(LoggingHandler.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at be.ondd.cris.service.ProductMapperService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f13b548.mapPageProductToPageProductJson(<generated>)
    at be.ondd.cris.controller.ProductController.findByParameters(ProductController.java:112)
    at be.ondd.cris.controller.ProductController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7aca546a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at be.ondd.cris.api.aspect.LoggingHandler.logAround(LoggingHandler.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at be.ondd.cris.api.aspect.AuditBusinessActivityHandler.logAround(AuditBusinessActivityHandler.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at be.ondd.cris.controller.ProductController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7d33074.findByParameters(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at be.ondd.cris.api.http.CorrelationFilter.doFilter(CorrelationFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4802] (through reference chain: be.ondd.cris.service.integration.util.RestResponsePage["pageable"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    ... 149 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what doesn't work? any exception trace for us?

Comment: consuming a service using REST Templates will result in `Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`. The `Page`, `Pageable` and `Sort` classes don't seem very JSon friendly.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace in your question.

Comment: question edited. Please keep in mind that I did get around the exception. My question is about the preferred and standard way to handle paging using Spring Data and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a Jackson module to my Application Context:

```java
@Bean
public SimpleModule pageJsonModule(Mapper mapper) {
    return new PageJsonModule(mapper);
}

/**
 * Simple Jackson module registering a serializer for the {@link Page} from spring data.
 * Can be dropped if the controllers all return something else than this not JSON friendly type (e.g. HAL response)
 * @see RestResponsePage
 */
private static class PageJsonModule extends SimpleModule {

    final Mapper mapper;

    PageJsonModule(Mapper mapper) {
        super("spring.data.page.module");
        this.mapper = mapper;

        this.addSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Page>() {
            /**
             * will copy fields from the {@link Page} to the JSON friendly POJO {@link RestResponsePage}
             * @param value a {@link Page} of any type
             * @param gen see parent
             * @param serializers see parent
             * @throws IOException see parent
             */
            @Override
            public void serialize(Page value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                RestResponsePage page = new RestResponsePage();

                // manually copy fields as dozer mapper doesn't seem to handle Page right
                page.getContent().addAll(value.getContent());
                page.setLast(value.isLast());
                page.setTotalElements(value.getTotalElements());
                page.setTotalPages(value.getTotalPages());
                page.setNumber(value.getNumber());
                page.setNumberOfElements(value.getNumberOfElements());
                page.setSize(value.getSize());
                page.setFirst(value.isFirst());
                page.setSort(mapper.map(value.getSort(), RestResponsePage.Sort.class));

                // serialize using default behavior
                serializers.defaultSerializeValue(page, gen);
            }

            @Override
            public Class<Page> handledType() {
                return Page.class;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then reading a response is just mapping to the `RestResonsePage` which is a simple POJO:

```
/**
 * Originally this POJO was extending {@link org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl}.
 * As of Spring Data release train Kay, {@link org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl} was not deserializing correctly with Jackson.
 * <br><br>
 * This should be replaced by a more generic Page Resource or some more standard paging mechanism
 *
 * @param <T> type of the elements from the content list
 */
public class RestResponsePage<T> implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3248189030448292002L;

    public static class Sort {

        private String direction = "ASC";
        private String nullHandling = "NATIVE";
        private boolean ascending = true;
        private String property;
        private boolean ignoreCase;

        public String getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setDirection(String direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }

        public void setProperty(String property) {
            this.property = property;
        }

        public String getNullHandling() {
            return nullHandling;
        }

        public void setNullHandling(String nullHandling) {
            this.nullHandling = nullHandling;
        }

        public boolean isIgnoreCase() {
            return ignoreCase;
        }

        public void setIgnoreCase(boolean ignoreCase) {
            this.ignoreCase = ignoreCase;
        }

        public boolean isAscending() {
            return ascending;
        }

        public void setAscending(boolean ascending) {
            this.ascending = ascending;
        }
    }

    private List<T> content = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean last, first;
    private int totalPages, numberOfElements, size, number;
    private long totalElements;
    private Sort sort;

    public List<T> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<T> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean isLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(boolean last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public boolean isFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(boolean first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public long getTotalElements() {
        return totalElements;
    }

    public void setTotalElements(long totalElements) {
        this.totalElements = totalElements;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public int getNumberOfElements() {
        return numberOfElements;
    }

    public void setNumberOfElements(int numberOfElements) {
        this.numberOfElements = numberOfElements;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Sort getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public void setSort(Sort sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was mapping to a custom `PageResponse`, similar to Rwanou's answer.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PageResponse<T> {
    private List<T> content;
    private int totalPages;
    private int totalElements;
    private int size;
    private int number;
    private int numberOfElements;
    private boolean first;
    private boolean last;
    private CustomPageable pageable;

    //getters & setters

    public Page<T> pageImpl() {
        return new PageImpl<>(getContent(), getPageable(), getTotalElements());
    }
}
```

The main problem seems to be that the parser has difficulties parsing the `Pageable` interface. Using the implementations `AbstractPageRequest` or `PageRequest` doesn't work either though, because both don't have a default constructor. 
For this reason I changed the type of `PageResponse.pageable` to `CustomPageable`, which is just a wrapper for `PageRequest`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomPageable extends PageRequest {
    public CustomPageable() {
        super(0, Constants.PAGE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

With these two classes, no further Jackson configuration was needed.